# Get the Selected Minimum Price Row's Columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM Products P
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT  COALESCE(CP.NewPrice, CP.Price, 2147483647) AS MinimumChildPrice
            --,SelectedMinimumPriceRow.Promotion
    FROM    Products CP
    WHERE   CP.ParentID = P.ID
) AS C
```

The problem is `SelectedMinimumPriceRow.Promotion`. I need to select this extra Promotion column of selected Minimum Price/NewPrice?

For example if I have,

```
  ID  ParentID  Promotion  Price  NewPrice
   ----------------------------------------
   1    NULL       a          81       52
   2    1          b          11       81
   3    1          c          91       14
   4    1          d          11       25
   5    1          e          10       61
```

For `ID=1`, the minimum price will be 14.  So, I need to select `c` as well.

Comment: *I need to select this extra Promotion column of selected Minimum Price/NewPrice?* What is your problem? You do? You don't? How are we meant to do? Things that aren't questions should end in a question-mark?

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: What - exactly - would be your desired result?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I am getting the minimum price but I need to select the promotion of the selected minimum price. For example, in the above example, 14 is the minimum child price of `id = 1` parent. I need to select `c` values as well.

Comment: In which row should `c` appear, and with which field name? What should be the value for the other rows?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, check my example. See `c` is in 3rd row which is also the row of minimum prices `14`

Comment: @user960567 Yes, I do understand where `c` is coming from, you're just not showing how you want it to appear in your query result. On all rows? Just the parent row? In an entirely separate select statement?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, just parent row. I need to replace `SelectedMinimumPriceRow.Promotion` with appropriate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply replace your OUTER APPLY query with a TOP 1 query ordering by price, that will allow you to grab any column;

```
SELECT * FROM Products P
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(CP.NewPrice, CP.Price, 2147483647) MinimumChildPrice,
                 promotion MinimumChildPricePromotion
    FROM    Products CP
    WHERE   CP.ParentID = P.ID
    ORDER BY COALESCE(CP.NewPrice, CP.Price, 2147483647)
) AS C
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2b67/1).